# How to import my own current package using venv Python?

Tags: python

This problem may be kind of confusing, but I'm currently working on an open source python package. The folder structure looks as follows:

```
my_package:
  |- __init__.py
  |- file.py
  |- example.py
```

Each file looks as follows, respectively:

```py
# __init__.py
from my_package.file import test
```

```py
# file.py
def test():
  print('Hello world')
```

```py
# example.py
from my_package.file import test

test()
```

Once I use `source venv/bin/activate` and I try to execute my example with `python my_package/example.py` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/Development/personal-projects/my_package/my_package/example.py", line 4, in <module>
    from my_package.file import test
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package'
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advice.

**Update**

Following Abdul suggestion I change my example.py file with:

```py
# example.py
from .file import test

test()
```

The output what I got was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/Development/personal-projects/my_project/my_project/example.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .file import test
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

In case it helps, this is my current system data:

- OS: Manjaro Linux x86_64
- Kernel: 5.17.6-1-MANJARO
- python version: 3.10.4
- pip version: 21.0

Using venv:

- pip version 22.0.4

Comment: Can you try `from .file import test` in your `__init__`.py?

Comment: Sure, give my a moment

Comment: I will update my question with the output

Comment: You need to make sure the current working directory [the location from which you are invoking the script] is the same folder where `my_package` is available. Or you have to set  it.

Comment: Yes @Kris, all the files I've mentioned are in the same current working directory.

Comment: Btw, @AbdulNiyasPM, I've updated my question with the output of your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the package. There should be a `setup.py` folder at the root directory of the project. Go to that directory in your terminal, and run

```
python -m pip install --editable .
```

This will install that package (and any dependencies) in your virtual env.

By specifying `--editable`, it will also update any time you make a change to the source code, allowing you to develop locally without re-installing it after every code change.

Comment: Or `pip install -e .` to save some keystrokes.

Comment: It works now, but shouldn't python recognize that I'm trying to import something from my own current package?

Comment: It has also added a new line in the `requirements.txt` file after I run `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, something like: `-e git+ssh://...` is that ok?

Comment: @AnthonyLuzquiños there's two major ways of specifying dependencies. A `requirements.txt` and the `setup.py`/`setup.cfg`, use whichever the project you're contributing to uses.  That is a weird dependency to add however-  probably don't commit that back to the project?

Comment: @AnthonyLuzquiños and yes, sorta. Python will add the directory of your `__main__` script to its `sys.path` lookup path, so normally it'll find sibling script, but things get complicated when stuff gets put into subdirectories. So sometimes it can find the package, sometimes not. Best to just make a proper package and pip install it, so it can be imported everywhere (including in tests, for instance)